# How i can get the Author of list item using New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue

Tags: development, pnp, office-365-developer

I have this script inside my PNP script to get the Author of the list items:-

```
 $ApprovalListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List "tickets" -PageSize 1 -ScriptBlock { Param($items) $items.Context.ExecuteQuery()} | ForEach-Object {
 
  $ctx = Get-PnPContext
  $spSourceWeb= $ctx.Web
 
  $Approver = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue($spSourceWeb, $_["Author"])
  $Approver = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue($_["Author"])
  $Approver
 }
```

but i am getting errors :-

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "FieldUserValue" and the argument count: "1".
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "FieldUserValue" and the argument count: "2".
```

any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like [FieldUserValue class has a constructor that accepts parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee536140(v=office.15)).

Instead of `New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue`, you can simply use `$_["Author"].LookupValue` and `$_["Author"].LookupId`.

Comment: thanks it worked